# CoreOS - Unable to access /mnt due to Permissions issue on /var/lib/docker

Tags: linux, docker, coreos

Im trying to copy a file to a docker container using the /mnt but I get this weird error when trying to sudo into the docker folder on CoreOS.

Core User:

```
core@dockermanager ~ $ cd /var/lib/docker
-bash: cd: /var/lib/docker: Permission denied
```

Sudo:

```
core@dockermanager ~ $ sudo cd /var/lib/docker
sudo: cd: command not found
```

Anyone else encounter this/know the explantion?

Exec-Driver - native-0.2
Kernel 3.18.6
CoreOS 607.0.0

Thanks for all the comments as I am relatively new to the Docker environment.

It isn't an ideal way nor what I would choose to do, but Im trying to run a testing environment for Drupal and wanted to add a theme and FTP isnt available.

Comment: `cd` is a shell builtin, not an external command.

Comment: right, you probably want something like sudo su   then, once you are root do the cd /var/lib/docker.  but, i don't think this is the right way to move files into a docker container, normally you would start the container and use the -v switch to mount the host file you want in the container.

Comment: Yeah, @Greg is right, this is a bad idea. You might be able to do something by piping input into a docker exec command though. However, the real question is - why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Run `sudo -s` and then `cd /var/lib/docker`.

Your first command doesn't work because the core user doesn't have permissions to access that folder.  Your second command doesn't work because sudo is not running your command inside of a shell that interprets it like you expect.